# Unwanted White line between banner and body

Tags: html, css

I am making a subscription box type website in Brazil. I made a banner  and underneath it is a white line.I want to remove it, and already did so by using display: block; but to no avail. This is my first time writing up a site so there might be a few mistakes.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px
}
#menu {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #383027;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#menu ul {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px 150px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff5e6;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: #e4a251;
}
#divider {
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #b68a20;
}
#body {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #faebc9;
}
#footer {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #2d2419;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="home2.html">
        <img src="paonamesalogoofficial.png" align="left">
      </a>
      <ul align="center">
        <li><a href="home2.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="planos.html">PLANOS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="areadeatuacao.html">ATUAÇÃO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="perguntasfrequentes.html">PERGUNTAS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="assineagora.html">ASSINE AGORA</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="divider"></div>

    <div id="header">
      <img src="bannerpao1.png" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div id="divider"></div>

    <div id="body"></div>

    <div id="divider"></div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That white line is, basically, this missing image `<img src="bannerpao1.png" width="100%">`.

Comment: Since the banner is inside the <body> tag, I recommend you to use the words "page content" or simply "content" instead of "body" to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `display` type of your image inside the header to `block`, because it defaults to `inline` which gives you some pixels of free space below the text-baseline, and as everyone knows inline elements *are* treated as text.

See the solution below.

Also if you'd checked this using an inspection tool in any modern browser, you'd have noticed that not the header had whitespace underneath it, but only the image. If you'd given the header a background-color, you'd have noticted it connected directly to the div below. In my solution I've given the header a `background-color` of `red`.

```css
<style> body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px
}
#menu {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #383027;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#menu ul {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px 150px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff5e6;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: #e4a251;
}
#header {
    background-color: red;
}
#header img {
    display: block;
}
#divider {
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #b68a20;
}
#body {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #faebc9;
}
#footer {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #2d2419;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Paozinho</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="home2.html">
        <img src="paonamesalogoofficial.png" align="left">
      </a>
      <ul align="center">
        <li><a href="home2.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="planos.html">PLANOS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="areadeatuacao.html">ATUAÇÃO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="perguntasfrequentes.html">PERGUNTAS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="assineagora.html">ASSINE AGORA</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="divider"></div>

    <div id="header">
      <img src="bannerpao1.png" width="100%">
    </div>

    <div id="divider"></div>

    <div id="body"></div>

    <div id="divider"></div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the solution and explanation to it!

Comment: If it has really worked, then please mark the answer as the solution. This will encourage users to keep answering future questions.